# RDCOMClient + Outlook email search using date interval in R

Tags: r, date, outlook, rdcomclient

I am trying to search outlook mail giving date as parameter in search.

right now I am searching full mailbox then filtering on the basis of received date but problem is by this way it is reading all mail each time. I want a solution where I can search directly by date interval so that it will return mails falling in between date interval.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

outlook_app <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
search<-outlook_app$AdvancedSearch("Inbox","urn:schemas:mailheader:date > '2019-05-22 00:14:10 IST'")
results <- search$Results()
results$Count()
```

I tried this but it is not working for me. I want all mails came after mentioned date.

Comment: I think you will not be able to just use  ">" to get the emails, just like it's point out in the stack's page where you get the code. I asked the member here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964208/rdcomclient-outlook-email-search-using-date-in-r maybe he will give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not specify the time zone (IST). '2019-05-22 00:14:10' is what you need.

Comment: got the result. Thanks

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks.